# Different hyphenation for tabular cells with same text and width due to multirow

Tags: tables, hyphenation, multirow

How can the same text in different tabular cells with the same width get hyphenated in a different way?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{6em}|p{12em}|p{7.5em}|}
\hline
\multirow[t]{3}{=}{Uebergang zum Regelbetrieb}
   & Anzahl Leerfahrten
      & \multirow[t]{3}{=}{Statistische Auswertung, ggf. Simulation} \\
   & Gefahrene Leerkilometer
      & \\
   & Anzahl der Personal- und Fahrzeugwechsel
      & \\
\hline
Auswirkung auf anderen Bahnverkehr
   & Streuung von Verspaetungen auf eigentlich nicht betroffene Linien
      & Statistische Auswertung, ggf. Simulation\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The result looks really odd:

[image]

Since I'm using multirow (version 2.1), this seems to cause the effect. How can one avoid this?

Comment: I have minimized the code and made it self-contained. I have no answer (yet), but with the minimized code the chances are higher that someone else picks up the challenge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your "normal" cell uses full justification (which actually is undesirable for such a narrow text). And `\multirow` uses `\raggedright`, so this gives a different hyphenation.

Actually, the `multirow` setup can be changed. Like if you remove the `\raggedright, you will get the same in both cells. Do this with

```
\renewcommand{\multirowsetup}{}
```

The alternative (which I think is better) is to also use `\raggedright` in the other cells.

Comment: Thank you very much! Actually, this is part of a longtable, thus, using raggedright or RaggedRight might get a little bit complicated. Is there any way to do this for singular cells within longtable? I don't want to exchange my longtable environment for LTXtable (other difficulties then).

Comment: For a single cell, use `{\raggedright Statistische Auswertung, ggf. Simulation\par}`. Even for `longtable` you can use a column specifier of `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{7.5em}` if you also have `\usepackage{array}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the column specifier worked very well! RaggedRight was also possible, just for some reason it would not be allowed using P columns defined as '\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}'. That's why I thought of using LTXtable in the first place.

Comment: Put the `\hspace{0pt}` **before** the `\arraybackslash`.